# Is it possible to see the back of an object traveling at relativistic speeds?

Tags: special-relativity, geometry

A while ago someone told me it's possible to see the opposite side of an object when it's moving at relativistic speeds. I don't remember where I heard this, and they didn't give me an explanation, but I've been trying to think if it could be true. As far as I can tell it's not true for objects with constant velocity, no matter the speed or direction (I'll omit my reasoning as the burden of proof is not on me yet). I'm pretty sure it's also not true for accelerating objects. Has anyone else heard this claim, or can anyone think of why it might be true?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terrell_rotation

Comment: @BowlOfRed I have just read that entry and it says nothing about whether the "rotation" shows you anything that you would _not_ expect to see, such as the back of an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a word: no.

When you appear to "see around" an object in SR visualizations, you are seeing *exactly the same parts* of it as you would if you were stationary, but the object is projected further forward than it really is by aberration when you move at relativistic speeds relative to the "scenery".

If you imagine you are in a doorway you can see the inside edges only.  Those edges are *exactly* what you would see if you were moving at high speed *at the same location*, but in that case they appear in front of you , and look "inside out" to keep the edges facing you as when you were stationary.  At the *exact* moment you pass through the doorway they will actually appear to form a *circle* in front of you!  The plane you are standing in when stationary becomes projected into a cone in front of you, which closes up as your speed relative to your surroundings increases.

It is unfortunate that early analyses used a sphere rather than a doorway, leading to the idea of (Terrell) "rotation".

It might help to watch one of the videos I made [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z0HGGYfcyqI&list=PLvGnzGhIWTGR-O332xj0sToA0Yk1X7IuI&index=2).  It is easier to see than to explain!  The "goalposts" are just like door frames.  There is a fuller description of what you are seeing in the [playlist page](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLvGnzGhIWTGR-O332xj0sToA0Yk1X7IuI).

Comment: This https://www.spacetimetravel.org/filme/wuerfelketten/wuerfelketten-xe-320x240.mp4 suggests otherwise as one can clearly see the back of the die even if the die is in front of the observer

Comment: @ZeroTheHero I would expect a "six" to be visible in that case ;)  Seriously though I hope you realize that when you see the "four" the die is actually _behind_ you!  It is outside the "cone" that I mentioned above.  My videos should not contradict _anything_ on the spacetimetravel site.

Comment: that’s not my understanding.  Clearly the die is still in the field of view, in font (although not directly in front) of the observer.  I understand the field of view will change: is that what you mean by “cone”?

Comment: Then it should be ;) If you watch the first video I linked to, you will see a circle of magenta dots on the "return trip".  They mark, in real time, what is in front of you (inside the dots) and what is behind you (outside them).  The "cone" has its tip at your eye, and those dots are arbitrary points equidistantly down the cone.  But, most importantly, you must realize that the die _really is behind you_ when you see the four!  This is why I dislike the term "rotation" for the effect.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero imagine you are stationary, and your body defines a plane separating "in front" from "behind".  Now, as you increase in speed "relativistically", imagine that plane closing like an umbrella around you so you can only see forwards, down the open end of the umbrella.  That is the cone, except _in reality_ the umbrella is transparent so you can see though it to what is behind, even though you are looking forwards.  That is the best I can do to explain I think!

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking at the “back side” of a moving object, it is moving away from you. If it is moving away at a relativistic speed, the light which it emits (or reflects) will be subject to a large Doppler shift, and may no longer be in the visible part of the spectrum.